# What does it mean by 'local settings aware' in printf() function of php

Tags: php, string, function, string-formatting

I know that for printf() function in php there are two format specifiers:

%f - Floating-point number (local settings aware)

%F - Floating-point number (not local settings aware)

Now what does it mean by "local settings aware"?

Is it possible to change local settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the locale you have on your server, the formatted string could be different. You can change the locale by using `setlocale` (you need to have the `locale` extension installed if you want it to work);

E.g:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,'de_DE.utf8');
printf ('%F', 1.234); //this prints 1.234
printf ('%f', 1.234); //this prints 1,234
```

Answer (score 0):

By Local settings aware , it implies that the output shown is based on certain local settings i.e. based on the certain geographical location that people uses to denote something or to show something . So , If you want to show certain format based on different geographical location you can make use of (local settings aware) type specifiers.

Both `%f` and `%F` will print same output unless local settings are changed using `setlocale()` function.

---

for local settings or setlocale() you can refer : 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php